# show that 210 is a triangular number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that 210 is a triangular number. Would it suffice to solve the equation 210=((n)(n+1))/2 ? Then n is equal to 20 and -21but n in this case must be positive, so 210 would be the 20th triangular number.

Comment: Sounds like you got this under control, my man. In other words, yes, it suffices.

Comment: Your solution's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed, your solution suffices. Well done!